# Filter Views using URL Parameters in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

I am using iframe in extjs i want to show different different view on the basis of url parameter.

```
items: [{
         xtype: "component",
         autoEl: {
         tag: "iframe",
         src: "/xyz/bin/view/Main/?key=abcd",
         html: "Loading...",
         }
        }]
```

Here I am showing xyz web application index page, I want to show another page of this application from url params in same iframe. How can we do this?

https://localhost/DEMOApp/client=ABC&page=sop1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution for this problem. I did this by adding listener afterrender and got the iframe object and set src.

```
listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
              var params=Ext.urlDecode(location.search.substring(1));
              Ext.get('iframe').dom.src = "http://www.google.com";                                                 

        this.getEl().on('load', function () {
                  console.log('loaded');
                });
           }
```